# List all files with its encoding in directory

Tags: macos, terminal, encoding

I need to know the encoding of all files in a specific directory.  Best case it would be create as a deep list.

Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't the `file` command tell you what you want to know?

Comment: I don´t know... does it? :-D

Comment: You tell me! Run `file *` and see if this what you are looking for. You can also combine it with `find`, as in `find -type f ... -exec file {} \;` or `find -type f ... | xargs file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's possible on Macs.  You should be able to use the following command which should include the encoding within the output listing.

```
file -I *
```

Cheers

Comment: thank you very much! 
If you know, what you have to search for, it´s really easy! :-D

I think I have to mention that I am new on OSX.. ^^

Comment: But, is there a way to list the files from child directories, too?

I already looked at the reference for files but wasn´t able to figure it out.

Comment: Try something like this.     "find . -type f | xargs file -I"  without quotations.